# Verification of Okta token in Python

Tags: python, jwt, okta

I would like to verify an Okta token (RS256) in python. I have tried to find the solution online but have not managed to get it to work:

I have tried this so far:

```
from py_jwt_validator import PyJwtValidator, PyJwtException
jwt = OKTA_TOKEN
try:
    PyJwtValidator(jwt)
except PyJwtException as e:
    print(f"Exception caught. Error: {e}")
```

throwing the error:
Okta-Specific: Access Tokens can not be validated locally without a Custom Authorization Server.

I have also tried to use the okta endpoint /introspect, but I keep on getting Response 405. I try to do get request to introspect/client_id=CLIENT_ID&token_type_hint=access_token&token=TOKEN

I also tried several other packages including okta_jwt (complains about ErrorKey : "jwks_uri")...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question. I can use the /introspect endpoint of okta:

```
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = ".../oauth2/v1/introspect/"

token = TOKEN
client_id = YOUR_CLIENT_ID
data = "client_id={}&token_type_hint=access_token&token={}".format(client_id, token)
response = http.request('POST', url, body=data, headers=headers)

decoded_response = response.data.decode('utf-8')
json_response = json.loads(decoded_response)
```

json_response["active"] will then be true if the token has been validated and false if its not the case.